# Multiple definitions for function templates with float, trying to resolve linker error

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, linker-errors, multiple-definition-error

I'm working on a set of function templates and the compile just fine. You can see them working [here](https://godbolt.org/z/67abxP) on Compiler Explorer... The issue is when I try to use it with `T = float` within my project, it is failing to link due to multiple definitions... I've tried various things and can't seem to resolve this...

Here is my header file:

*cstr.h*

```
#pragma once

#include <stdint.h>

const uint8_t default_decimal_places = 8;

template<typename T>
const char* to_string(T value) {
    static char output_buffer[128];

    uint8_t negative = 0;
    bool isNegative = false;
    if (value < 0) {
        isNegative = true;
        negative = 1;
        value *= -1;
        output_buffer[0] = '-';
    }

    uint8_t size = 0;
    T sizeTest = value;
    while (sizeTest / 10 > 0) {
        sizeTest /= 10;
        size++;
    }

    uint8_t idx = 0;
    if (isNegative) {
        while (value / 10 > 0) {
            uint8_t remainder = value % 10;
            value /= 10;
            output_buffer[negative + size - idx] = remainder + '0';
            idx++;
        }
        uint8_t remainder = value % 10;
        output_buffer[negative + size - idx] = remainder + '0';
        output_buffer[negative + size + 1] = 0;
    }
    else {
        while (value / 10 > 0) {
            uint8_t remainder = value % 10;
            value /= 10;
            output_buffer[size - idx] = remainder + '0';
            idx++;
        }
        uint8_t remainder = value % 10;
        output_buffer[size - idx] = remainder + '0';
        output_buffer[size + 1] = 0;
    }

    return output_buffer;
}

template<typename T>
const char* to_string(T value, uint8_t decimal_places) {
    if (decimal_places > 20) decimal_places = 20;

    static char output_double_buffer[128];
    char* intPtr = (char*)to_string((int64_t)value);
    char* doublePtr = output_double_buffer;

    if (value < 0) {
        value *= -1;
    }

    while(*intPtr != 0) {
        *doublePtr = *intPtr;
        intPtr++;
        doublePtr++;
    }

    *doublePtr = '.';
    doublePtr++;

    T newValue = value - (int)value;

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < decimal_places; i++) {
        newValue *= 10;
        *doublePtr = (int)newValue + '0';
        newValue -= (int)newValue;
        doublePtr++;
    }

    *doublePtr = 0;
    return output_double_buffer;
}

template<>
inline const char* to_string<float>(float value, uint8_t decimal_places) {
    if (decimal_places > 14) decimal_places = 14;

    static char output_float_buffer[128];
    char* intPtr = (char*)to_string((int64_t)value);
    char* floatPtr = output_float_buffer;

    if (value < 0) {
        value *= -1;
    }

    while(*intPtr != 0) {
        *floatPtr = *intPtr;
        intPtr++;
        floatPtr++;
    }

    *floatPtr = '.';
    floatPtr++;

    float newValue = value - (int)value;

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < decimal_places; i++) {
        newValue *= 10;
        *floatPtr = (int)newValue + '0';
        newValue -= (int)newValue;
        floatPtr++;
    }

    *floatPtr = 'f';
    floatPtr++;
    *floatPtr = 0;
    return output_float_buffer;
}
```

and it's cpp file...

```
#include "cstr.h"
```

Class that calls them...

*BasicRenderer.cpp*

```
void BasicRenderer::Print(double val, uint8_t decimal_places) {
    Print(to_string(val, decimal_places));
}

void BasicRenderer::Print(float val, uint8_t decimal_places) {
    Print(to_string(val, decimal_places));
}
```

However, when I run this in my application... GCC is giving me this linker error...

```
skilz420@skilz-PC:~/skilzOS/kernel$ make kernel
!==== COMPILING src/cstr.cpp
gcc -ffreestanding -fshort-wchar -c src/cstr.cpp -o lib/cstr.o
!==== LINKING
ld -T kernel.ld -static -Bsymbolic -nostdlib -o bin/kernel.elf  lib/kernel.o  lib/cstr.o  lib/BasicRenderer.o
ld: lib/BasicRenderer.o: in function `char const* to_string<float>(float, unsigned char)':
BasicRenderer.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `char const* to_string<float>(float, unsigned char)'; lib/kernel.o:kernel.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
make: *** [Makefile:33: link] Error 1
skilz420@skilz-PC:~/skilzOS/kernel$
```

I even tried moving its definition to the `CPP` file, inlining it, etc... It's been a long night and I just want to get this to work before I call it a night... The `double` by itself works fine, but does this when I try to add in and specialize the `float` variant, and yes the `float` behaves differently than the `double`.

Comment: This is not a [mcve].

Comment: You may consider a different name, like `to_cstring`, to avoid collisions with `std::to_string`, which returns a `std::string`. Also, I guess those are meant for "immediate" use, given the returned pointer to a `static` local variable, but have you considered an interface more similar to [`std::to_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars)?

Comment: @Bob__ I'm actually following a video series and I'm staying close to the implementation within the video... After they started to write the same function for each type... I just tried to template those functions... The Print functions that use these actually belong to a class right now... so there should be no "collisions" with the `stl` functions. So far I'm not using these functions outside of the set of class's that uses them, and we're not using the `stl` as it's a series on writing a custom OS from scratch...

Comment: @super Yeah, I forgot to add the class-functions that are calling these... and I had walked away from the computer, got a drink and came back... then I realized what was causing the linking error... you can see that from my answer below.

Comment: @super I also added the functions that called these function templates in the state that they were before I was able to fix them...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after getting a drink and coming back... I found out what the issue was... It's fine the way it is within the header file. The issue was within another class that was using it. For example...

```
void BasicRenderer::Print(const char* str ) {
    // code implementation
}

void BasicRenderer::Print(double val, uint8_t decimal_places) {
    Print(to_string(val, decimal_places);
}

void BasicRenderer::Print(float val, uint8_t decimal_places);
    Print(to_string(val, decimal_places);
}
```

And this was what was causing the linker error...

I had to change them to the following...

```
void BasicRenderer::Print(double val, uint8_t decimal_places) {
    Print(to_string<double>(val, decimal_places);
}

void BasicRenderer::Print(float val, uint8_t decimal_places);
    Print(to_string<float>(val, decimal_places);
}
```

And now they both work. I had to explicitly instantiate them... This happened as I was refactoring my code to where I started to template these conversion and print functions... and for almost an hour I was staring at this problem scratching my head... *--eh--* `template<T = float> = headaches...`